# SchemaSpy error - KIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, sql-server, schemaspy

Getting an error while setting up SchemaSpy

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:2cabc4bd-ace9-4dd2-956f-4496ddf7bf0e
>
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Point to note that I have SQL installed on diff VM and using schemaspy from App server